# Rational Developer Application 9.1 Websphere 7.0 there aren't resources to add or remove

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-rad

I work with Rational Developer Application 9.1 for Websphere 7.0.

I downloaded a project using SCM Harvest plugin for RAD.

I have two projects. One of them is a EAR.

[image]

After downloading, I did some modifications in java classes and I want to build the project. I have disabled build and clean options

[image]

When I click `add or remove` in the websphere server, I get the error

```
"There aren't resources to add or remove"
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

The tools allows you to add Java EE modules to the server. However, based on the screencap that you have, the project is not imported as Java EE projects and thus the tools won't allow you to add those projects to the server.

It looks like vaiEAR is already an Eclipse project before and based on the list of metadata file, my guess is it was an EAR project before.  If it is, you can try to do a **File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace** and point to the root directory of your vaiEAR (and do the same for the child modules.

After that, you should be able to see the EAR in the add and remove dialog.